# How do I run a Debian init.d script manually, not at boot?

Tags: debian, boot, init.d, debian-wheezy

How do I stop an init.d server from running on boot, but still allow running it manually?

Answer (score 11):

See the man page for `update-rc.d`.

To stop a service from running at boot:

```
update-rc.d -f servicename remove
```

Or:

```
update-rc.d servicename stop 20 2 3 4 5 .
```

If you have Debian squeeze or later, or Ubuntu 12.10 or later:

```
update-rc.d servicename disable
```

---

To allow a service to run at boot:

```
update-rc.d servicename defaults
```

If you have Debian squeeze or later, or Ubuntu 12.10 or later:

```
update-rc.d servicename enable
```

---

To run the service manually:

```
service servicename start
service servicename restart
```

To stop the service manually:

```
service servicename stop
```

Comment: According to the manpage, `-f servicename remove` is technically only supposed to be used when you're removing the associated initscript entirely; `disable` is more correct.

Comment: @tgies The `disable` option may not exist on the target system. It appears to have been introduced in squeeze, and doesn't exist on Ubuntu systems at all.

Comment: It definitely exists on at least Ubuntu 12.10; I actually had occasion to use it yesterday. sysv-rc version 2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu13. But I didn't know it was a recently-added thing, so thank you.

Comment: @MichaelHampton as a note, all versions of Debian older than Squeeze have reached end of life.  Lenny is no longer covered by the security team.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen I've incorporated those into my answer. Keep in mind that we like answers that will be useful not only today, but hopefully years from now. :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton, at the same time, if you're still using Lenny or older you're risking unpatched vulnerabilities.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen You'd be surprised what sorts of antiques are lurking in dark data centers and server closets... but that's neither here nor there.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian Squeeze and up:

```
sudo update-rc.d server-name disable
```

To reverse:

```
sudo update-rc.d server-name enable
```

Comment: These options don't seem to exist?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, what distro and version are you on?  They exist on Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Looks like these were introduced with Squeeze. So don't count on them being present on your legacy systems.